# How should I name an "umbrella" type sanely?

Tags: c#, oop, naming-conventions, naming

This has "always" bothered me...

Let's say I have an interface `IFiddle` and another interface that does nothing more than aggregate several distinct `IFiddle`s:

```
public interface IFiddleFrobbler
{
    IFiddle Superior { get; }
    IFiddle Better { get; }
    IFiddle Ordinary { get; }
    IFiddle Worse { get; }
    IFiddle Crackpot { get; }
}
```

(The concrete `IFiddleFrobbler`s and `IFiddle`s depend on configurations and are created by a factory.)

I repeatedly stumble on the naming of such "umbrella" types - I want to exchange the "Frobbler" with something descriptive.

- "Collection", "List" and "Set" aren't good enough, in the sense that it's not a collection/list/set where elements can be enumerated, added or removed.
- "Manager" is out, because there's no management being done - the factory and configurations handle that.
- "Aggregator" makes it sound like picked straight from the GoF book (although I don't think they would break "the law of demeter" - that's out of topic here).

Please, enlighten me, what's a good naming scheme for my "umbrella" types?

---

**Edit:** As [xtofl pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324992/how-should-i-name-an-umbrella-type-sanely/2325055#2325055), there's actually more semantics to this than I first exposed above. If I instead do the following, I think my need is clearer:

```
//
// Used for places where the font width might need
// to be tapered for a rendered  text to fit.
//
public interface ITaperableFont
{
    Font Font { get; }
    Boolean CanTaper { get; }

    void Taper();
}

//
// Used for rendering a simple marked-up text in
// a restricted area.
//
public interface ITaperableFonts
{
    ITaperableFont Biggest{ get; }
    ITaperableFont Big { get; }
    ITaperableFont Normal { get; }
    ITaperableFont Small { get; }
    ITaperableFont Smallest { get; }
}
```

In fact, I've identified my problem in the real-life addition above as a design flaw, not a naming problem, the smell of which several people has pointed out below.

Comment: If you can't name it, then I smell something fishy in the design.

Comment: @Pop: Correct. It's a pragmatic way of making my life easier and I know it might be considered a smell.

Comment: In my company, we use `Bunny` for things we can't name.

Comment: @Earwicker: Yes, that's always an emergence exit when everything else fail.  :)

Comment: IDuck? walks like a duck, quakes like a duck, smells like a duck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the name you choose should be dependent on what you are trying to achieve. In the code example I'd say what you are doing is setting up a rating, so I'd probably call it `IFiddleRating`

As a general answer I'd say "it depends" :) I find its a good idea to name stuff after what its trying to do, not what it "is"

Comment: In general, I agree on "I find its a good idea to name stuff after what its trying to do, not what it "is"", but not in this specific case. This is just a behavior-less type, almost, but not exactly, like a collection/list/set. It's a pragmatic way of making my life easier (which I *know* might be a smell, but that's not the topic)

Comment: At least for this case, you appear to have found the semantics behind this collection.

Comment: @xtofl: Hmmm... You might actually be correct there, now that I think about it!

Answer (score 7):

Can you just use the plural: `IFiddles`?

Comment: Beauty lies in the small things. Thanks.

Comment: The downside is that it differs from `IFiddle` by only one character: which, contradicts some style guides; still I reckon that a reader ought to be able see the difference, especially as the members of `IFiddles` are quite different from the members of `IFiddle`.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with you in that naming a class, interface or abstract class is really difficult to get right. Some possible names that I have used before which you might like are:

- xxx`Assistant`
- `Composite`xxx
- xxx`Coordinator`
- xxx`Group`

Answer (score 3):

As Pop said: "If you can't name it, then I smell something fishy in the design."

maybe rethink your design.

```
IFiddles : IDictionary<SomeType, IFiddle>
{
}
```

Update: If you want it to be readonly create an interface for that yourself:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>
{
     TValue this[TKey] { get; }
     int Count { get; }
     ...
}
```

Your life can still as easy as before.

Comment: Hmmm... But I explicitly don't want it to look like it's possible to manipulate the set of elements aggregated by `IFiddles`, so I would then have to throw `NotSupportedException` in all `Add`/`Remove` etc. implementations of `ICollection<IFiddle>` **and** document that fact.

Comment: I added the post according to your request :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really a problem of personal preference, so I fired up a thesaurus and looked for synonyms of "Family" (which could be ok in itself).

kin, classification, genre, group, kind, subdivision, association, affiliation, alliance, clan, clique, club, coalition, combination, combo, confederacy, confederation, congress, cooperative,  family, federation, fellowship, fraternity, gang, guild, league, mob, order, organization,  ring, society, sodality, sorority, syndicate, tie-in, tie-up, tribe, troops, troupe, zoo

I dropped a few which have a specific technical meaning (like union, ring, pool)... pick what you like best.